# magento 2 zipcode validation by select city and country in india only

Tags: zipcode

is it possible to select city state and country by validating zipcode in magento 2.I have jquery code for this. But i have no idea, how to integrate with code. any one guide me about this task?

Comment: Use mage array plugin for this